# Base type is not converting to derived type yet can call its functions and variables

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management

As far as i know created **base** type can't be casted into **derived** type on **OOP**. But i have encountered something like this and i wasn't expecting to work. Here is the example classes:

```
class Base {
public: 
    virtual void Call1() { std::cout << "Base call 1" << std::endl; }
    virtual void Call2() { std::cout << "Base call 2" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    void Call1() { std::cout << "Derived call 1" << std::endl; }
    void Call2() { std::cout << "Derived call 2" << std::endl; }

    void SetAll() { x = 15; y = 16; z = 16; } // Just random numbers
    
    int GetX() { return x; }
    int GetY() { return y; }       
    int GetZ() { return z; }
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

In the main program:

```
Base* b1 = new Base;
Derived* d1 = (Derived*)(b1); // This shouldn't be okay as far as i know

// How is this part working?
d1->SetAll();
std::cout << d1->GetX() << std::endl;
std::cout << d1->GetY() << std::endl;
std::cout << d1->GetZ() << std::endl;
```

Here is the output:

```
15
16
16
```

Even if the size of **derived** type is bigger, for some reason i can call it's function and manipulate it's variables of the derived type even if i didn't allocate enough **memory** for it because **Base** object is less in size. So how is this code works?

Comment: Are you familiar with *undefined behavior*?

Comment: Don't use c-style casts in C++. It lets you do really bad things.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` leads often to UB.

Comment: You can cast base types behind pointers to derived types only if the derived type you are casting it to is the actual type behind the pointer, otherwise it is undefined behavior. The C-style cast actually performs a number of different types of casts, including dynamic_cast which is used to do the type of cast mentioned above.

Comment: Sometimes you can use tools to catch things like this if you make a mistake. [Example using AddressSanitizer on your code](https://godbolt.org/z/56zv8osoq)

Comment: Using a *cast* means you are telling the compiler "This **should** be okay as far as I know, so ignore the error and shut up compiler and make it happen."  On my machine, your code compiles (with several warnings) and crashes when I attempt to run it... that's the magic of **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @topoly, it does not do a `dynamic_cast`, otherwise, the result would return `nullptr`. It does a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @ChrisMM yes you are correct, it performs a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @ChrisMM But it works with c++ style **static_cast<Derived*>(b1)** too. Is it something compiler specific ? I am using MSVC.

Comment: Yes, it would. Using a `static_cast`, it ensures that the types are convertible, nothing more (c-style does not care, that's all I meant by my comment). What you're really looking for is `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. The cast is not converting a base object into a derived object. It is converting a **pointer** to base into a **pointer** to derived. The object isn't involved at all.

Comment: @PeteBecker I changed the title thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is covered mostly by the comments, but there's one thing there I haven't seen yet: how the `SetAll()` method is setting memory, and *where* it is setting it.  For the record, what I describe below is what is *probably* happening, as you are heavily into "Undefined Behavior" here.

```cpp
Derived* d1 = (Derived*)(b1); // This shouldn't be okay as far as i know
```

As you say, this shouldn't and *is not OK*.  `d1` *thinks* it is pointing to a `Derived` class, but it really isn't.  But everything will *behave* like it is.  As others have said, you've essentially done a `reinterpret_cast` on the pointer.

```cpp
d1->SetAll();
```

What happens here is the `SetAll()` method will set the *memory locations* of where x, y, and z *would be* if d1 were pointing to an *actual* instance of `Derived`.  So you're overwriting memory you didn't allocate, but it's *often* still there.  So if `b1` is 0x00004000 (or whatever), then `d1->x` is 0x0004004, or 4 bytes (or 8, or compiler-dependent on how it lays the base and derived classes out) beyond the "start" of the `Base` class.  If `d1` actually pointed to a `Derived` it would be fine, but it points to a `Base` which means it's not pointing to an area of memory that it "owns".  And thus undefined behavior.

```cpp
std::cout << d1->GetX() << std::endl;
std::cout << d1->GetY() << std::endl;
std::cout << d1->GetZ() << std::endl;
```

Well `d1` *did write* to the areas it's now looking for `x`, `y`, and `z` from now, so it finds them.  The problem is that it wrote outside of where it was supposed to.

Short answer: use `dynamic_cast` if you can when converting between base and child classes.  It will return `nullptr` if it shouldn't be allowed.